# Printing number of letter occurrences in a string

Tags: c

```
void
countChar()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("source.txt", "r");

    char string[100], i;
    int c = 0, count[26] = {0}, x, y;

    for (i = 0; !feof(fp); i++) {
            fgets(string, 30, fp);
    }

    while (string[c] != '\0') {
        if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') {
            x = string[c] - 'a';
            count[x]++;
        }
        if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z') {
            y = string[c] - 'A';
            count[x]++;
        }       

        c++;
    }

    for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
        if (count[c] != 0)
            printf("%c = %d\n", c + 'A', count[c]);
}
```

I have this code wherein I'm supposed to be counting the number of occurrences of a letter in a string, but I can't seem to print out the number of capital letters correctly.

[image: small letters] This is how it is when I type in small letters.

[image: capital letters] And this is how it is when I type in capital letters.

Comment: Please do not include pictures of plain text. Adding them via cut&paste is preferred at SO.

Answer (score 2):

For starters this loop

```
for (i = 0; !feof(fp); i++) {
        fgets(string, 30, fp);
}
```

does not make sense. It is unclear why there is used the magic number 30. And after the  loop the array string will contain the last record read from the file.

The loop should look like

```
while ( fgets( string, sizeof( string ), fp ) != NULL )
{
    // count within the loop letters.
}
```

And within the body of the loop all characters should be countered.

Moreover in this if statement

```
    if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z') {
        y = string[c] - 'A';
        count[x]++;
    }
```

there is a typo. There should be at least

```
count[y]++;
```

instead of

```
count[x]++;
```

It is a bad idea to use the name `c` as an index. Use for example one of the following letters i, j, k, l, m, n.

Also instead of the two if statements you could to convert the current character to uppercase as for example

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

char c = toupper( ( unsigned char )string[i] );
```

Pay attention to that the a record can contain other characters apart from letters. In this case your program will have undefined behavior.

You could define an array of valid letters like for example

```
const char *letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

and then write

```
char c = toupper( ( unsigned char )string[i] );
const char *p = strchr( letters, c );

if ( p != NULL ) ++count[p - letters];

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
y = string[c] - 'A';
count[x]++;
```

You set y to be the index but use x, looks like you just need to replace the x with y to increment the right index

```
count[y]++;
```

Comment: @OP: you don't need `x` and `y`. One single variable is enough: you can use it independently in both branches of the `if`